# Removing bit at specific index

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

I'm basically trying to remove a bit from an integer at a specific index. That is, I do not want to unset/clear the bit; I actually want to strip it, so that every higher bit moves down, replacing the respective bit at its position. Visually, this could be compared to deleting an element from an array or removing a character from a string.

For the sake of clarity, some examples:

```
1011011 (original number)
    ^ index = 2
0101111 (result)

10000000000000000000000000000001
^ index = 31
00000000000000000000000000000001

1111111111111111111111111111110
                              ^ index = 0
0111111111111111111111111111111
```

Full of confidence, I started shifting some bits, and came up with the following Java method...

```
public static int removeBit(int num, int i) {
    int out = (num >>> (i + 1)) << i;
    out  |= (num << (32 - i)) >>> (32 - i);
    return out;
}
```

... which almost always works, except for some extreme cases:

```
10000000000000000000000000000001 (= Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
^ index = 31, results in:
10000000000000000000000000000001

1011011
      ^ index = 0, results in:
1111111
```

In other words, if the index is 0 or 31 (least or most significant bit), my method will output garbage.

I can't seem to wrap my head around it, and that's why I'm asking: How can I remove an arbitrary bit in a 32-bit integer?

I'm especially looking for the most performant way to do it in Java (smallest possible memory and CPU consumption), since this operation has to run at least a couple million times. That's why something like "convert it into a string, remove the char and convert it back" is out of the question.

Comment: I suspect this for the upper extreme: `num >>> (i + 1)`. Shifting by 32 is the same as not shifting at all (the right operand gets an AND mask treatment beforehand).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I suspected something like that, too. Do you have an idea on how I could change my method, so that this won't happen? Of course, I could incorporate some `if`s, but I thought there could be an easier option in terms of performance.

Comment: `if` is cheap, I wouldn't start worrying about that so early on. Just the fact that you are using a bit-twiddling approach will by itself guarantee excellent performance (a few nanos). First make it work, then profile, then optimize if necessary (very unlikely).

Comment: You said "so that every higher bit moves up".  Seems like the higher bits should move down or the lower bits up.

Comment: @HotLicks You're absolutely right. That was more of a translation problem (long story)...

Comment: `(32 - i)`---that's the source of the lower-end bug. Again you go above 31.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the shift counts rolled over to >= 32, which caused trouble.

Anyway, let's derive a way to do it.

Start by considering the two "pieces", the low piece (which gets copied in its original position and may be anywhere between 0 .. 31 bits long) and the high piece (which gets shifted down by one, and can also be between 0 .. 31 bits long). The total length of the pieces is always 31.

The mask for the low piece is obvious: `~(-1 << i)`

Which makes the mask for the high piece obvious: `~lowmask << 1`. The high piece is shifted anyway, so that shift can go.

Now all that's left is to take the pieces and OR them together, and you would get

```
static int removeBit(int x, int i)
{
    int mask = ~(-1 << i);
    return (x & mask) | ((x >>> 1) & ~mask);
}
```

Throw out the double negation:

```
static int removeBit(int x, int i)
{
    int mask = -1 << i;
    return (x & ~mask) | ((x >>> 1) & mask);
}
```

Comment: Great explanation, would never have gotten there myself. I think my brain wasn't built for bit operations ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity: Would it make a difference (performancewise) if we defined index 31 as the LSB and index 0 as the MSB? Or: Can I take of advantage of a statistical tendency that the bit is more likely to be on the right or left half of the integer?

Comment: @MCL mirroring the indexes can be done by using `-1 << (31 - i)` (equivalently, `-1 << (i ^ 31)`) as the mask, that would take an additional operation and the difference should be measurable (though small). I don't think there's any possibility to take advantage of any statistical tendency - it takes a constant amount of time anyway, at least on any processor with a barrel shifter.

Answer (score 1):

Just mask out the bits needed, no need to shift back and forth

```
public static int removeBit(int num, int index) {
    int mask = (1 << index) - 1;
    return ((num & ((~mask) << 1)) >>> 1) | (num & mask);
}
```

or

```
public static int removeBit(int num, int index) {
    int mask = (1 << index) - 1;
    return ((num >>> 1) & ~mask) | (num & mask);
}
```

Some platforms have very efficient [parallel bit extract](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pext) so if you can do the job in JNI or if Java has some intrinsic similar to [Bmi2.ParallelBitExtract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.bmi2.parallelbitextract?view=net-5.0) then you can do like this

```
public static int removeBit(int num, int index) {
    return Bmi2.ParallelBitExtract(num, ~(1 << index));
}
```

Comment: This code uncovered a bug in my symbolic bitmath analyzer, but it's still wrong. It's correct for `index = 0`, but for any other index it's only correct for example half the possible values for `num`. For example consider `index = 1` and `num = odd`. `mask = 1`, so the right hand side of the OR is always zero, and bit 0 of `num` never shows up in the result.

Comment: @harold just thought of it after seeing the question, haven't tested yet. I've just edit the code

Answer (score 1):

If it is important to use the minimum number of instructions, for these kind of bit shuffling it is often best to calculate the bits that need to be toggled and then use xor to apply that. Also here this saves one instruction compared to harold's solution:

```
static int removeBit(int x, int i)
{
    int mask = -1 << i;
    return ((x ^ (x >>> 1)) & mask) ^ x;
}
```

or

```
static int removeBit(int x, int i)
{
    return (((x ^ (x >>> 1)) >>> i) << i) ^ x;
}
```